# Unable to bind popup to polygon (geoJSON) using Leaflet

Tags: angular, leaflet, polygon, geojson

I am trying to add to the generated polygon a message that will be displayed when the user clicks on it in Angular.

I tried to create something based on the available materials on the Leftlet website, but I can't add the message to polygon. I used an identical method, for geojson pointing to a point, and everything works without a problem.

The materials I found, unfortunately, mostly show cases that work (e.g., the geojson point).

Geojson displays correctly on the map, the only problem is the lack of popup.

```
L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature,
            {
                style: function(feature) {
                    return {
                        "color": "#78c679",
                        "weight": 5,
                        "opacity": 0.9
                    }
                },
                onEachFeature: (feature, layer)=>{
                    layer.bindPopup('Test message');
                }
            }
        ).addTo(this.map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to solve the problem. All I had to do was change the map rendering option (preferCanvas).

```
this.map = L.map('map', {
        center: center,
        maxZoom: 19,
        zoom: 17,
        layers: [osm],
        preferCanvas: true
    });
```